# Error by Kerberos decryption key rollover

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, kerberos

Dear Microsoft Experts,

I'm having troubles rollover the Kerberos decryption key for my Azure AD SSO configuration.

When I process the following steps with Power Shell on my AADC Server:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect"

Import-Module .\AzureADSSO.psd1

New-AzureADSSOAuthenticationContext

Get-AzureADSSOStatus

$creds = Get-Credential

Update-AzureADSSOForest -OnPremCredentials $creds
```

Such as described in this kbase article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-sso-faq#how-can-i-roll-over-the-kerberos-decryption-key-of-the-azureadssoacc-computer-account

I'm getting the following Error-Message:

```
[13:17:37.747] [ 10] [ERROR] Uploading computer account information failed. Error message: Internal error: An error occurred 
during the 'DesktopSsoNumOfDomains' process. Contact support (Failed Request Id = '692dae89-91fc-4fc4-855d-3e77b3c0702c')
Update-AzureADSSOForest : Uploading computer account information failed. Error message: Internal error: An error occurred 
during the 'DesktopSsoNumOfDomains' process. Contact support (Failed Request Id = '692dae89-91fc-4fc4-855d-3e77b3c0702c')
At C:\Users\********\Desktop\Kerberos_Ticket_Rollover.ps1:11 char:1
+ Update-AzureADSSOForest -OnPremCredentials $creds
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-AzureADSSOForest], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.KerberosAuth.Powershell.PowershellCommands.UpdateAzureADSSOForestC 
   ommand
```

Does somebody has any idea how I can fix this issue?
It is not a rights issue.

Best regards

FlaEdLi

Comment: The server failed to process the data it received
. You may actually have to contact support to get the specific error.

Comment: Do you talk about Microsoft Support?

Comment: Azure specifically, but yes. They're the ones complaining and not providing specific details, therefore you should ask them.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to TLS 1.2 that now is mandatory. Add this before the command:

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12